# Sorting a query response from GAE datastore

Tags: java, list, sorting, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running a query on GAE's datastore:

```
List<Entity> messages =    
    datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(500));
```

I plan on manually adding a property to each message and would then like to sort the messages by the new property.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Ideally I'd like to sort by multiple variables.

Comment: And can't you just sort normally for some reason? Like with Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can make separate `java.util.Comparator<SortPropertyType>` implementations and then do a

```
Collections.sort(myList,myComparatorInstance);
```

do sort using a certain field.

Comment: Andrei - Thanks for your response.  Its been a long time since I've programmed. Could you please provide more details on the comparator impelementation or a short example?

Comment: Read here please: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html, especially the "Comparators" chapter

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I also found the link below very helpful: http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html